# Can I pay a previous quarter's estimated taxes with current quarter?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, estimated-taxes

I've never done estimated taxes before and I found out today is the [last day for the June 1 - August 31 period](https://www.irs.gov/faqs/estimated-tax/individuals/individuals-2) to pay estimated taxes. I went to the IRS site and saw how I can do it but there is something that isn't quite clear to me.

Since I missed the previous 2 periods (Jan 1 - March 31 & April 1 - May 31), can I not try to pay those in the same form that I pay June - August)?

One thing someone told me about estimated taxes is that it's always better to pay more than you think so you don't get penalized later but I don't really think that means just pay thousands more to cover myself for the previous periods I missed.

Thanks!

Comment: Just as a practical matter, the IRS is unlikely to look unless there are large amounts involved.  Remember, these are ESTIMATES.  So if you are single, and made $20K in the first half of the year, you would owe no tax on that if you estimated that you will make nothing in the second half.  Now if you make $30K in the third quarter, your estimate changes.  But you still don't know what you'll make in the fourth quarter.

Comment: @jamesqf I did run into that last year. It was my first time being "self-employed" so my income fluctuated drastically as I made more as the year went forward and I did end up with a penalty. I am technically salaried now but still labeled as "self-employed" so I do know what I make, but there is nothing taken off thus my wanting to do these estimated taxes today.

Based on this, do you think I can just lump Jan - Aug into one 1040es filing? This is the form I'm following https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040es.pdf

Comment: I'm certainly not an expert, just going by my own experience with a self-employment income that tends to come in largish chunks several months apart.  Personally, I would have lumped Jan-Aug into one 1040ES, on the theory that Jan-March would have given me an estimated 0 tax liability.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is, paying missed estimated taxes from previous quarters won't avoid a penalty if there is one, but the sooner you pay, the smaller the penalty (which is the interest on the underpaid amount from when it was due to when you paid) will be.

First, if on the last day of the year, your withholding (from paychecks, IRA conversions, etc.; not including estimated tax payments) reaches the safe harbor level, i.e. 90% of this year's tax liability, or 100% (110% for high earners) of last year's tax liability, you do not need to pay estimated taxes this year. This means that, if you have a W2 job for the rest of the year, and you can increase your withholding at that job in the rest of the year sufficiently so that it reaches the safe harbor level by the end of the year, you will not have a penalty for not having paid enough estimated taxes in earlier quarters. This (payments later in the year to cover missed payments earlier in the year) is something that withholding can do that estimated tax payments cannot do.

If your withholding does not reach the safe harbor level by the end of the year, then you need to pay estimated taxes each quarter, calculated through a combination of two methods. The first is that the safe harbor level is divided by 4, and that must tax needs to be paid each quarter; you are assumed to have paid 1/4 of your withholding each quarter, and the rest needs to be paid by estimated tax each quarter. The second method is the "annualized income" method, which uses the actual income up to that quarter to calculate the estimated tax due; this is useful for cases when your income increased in later quarters. So if your income increased in later quarters this year, it is possible (depending on the exact calculation) that under the annualized income method you didn't need to pay estimated taxes in earlier quarters. However, if your income is pretty consistent through the year then this is not going to help you.

Another thing that might help for the first quarter is, if you had withholding from your job, and you get a paycheck between the 1st and 15th of the month, you can count the actual amount withheld from paychecks up to the estimated tax due date for that quarter as withholding for that quarter (instead of using 1/4 of withholding for the whole year). This allows you to use withholding for a slightly longer period (up to April 15th) for the first quarter (decreasing the required estimated taxes for the first quarter), though it might make it worse for the second quarter (since it's less than half a year to the 2nd quarter estimated tax deadline).

Comment: So there was a lot there... I can summarize my status by saying that I am technically "self employed" though I work for a startup and nothing is currently taken out of my paychecks. When I filed earlier this year for the 2020 season, I did have a penalty that showed up.

https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040es.pdf I feel like if I just follow this I should be fine. But in this scenario, it does sound like you are saying that I can jumble Jan - August into this payment. I'll still pay a penalty on Q1 & Q2, but not as much as if I wait until later to do Q1 & Q2. Is that right?

Comment: @JoeL: right . .

Comment: @JoeL: It would likely be in your best interest to hire a professional to do your taxes for you. Normally US taxes are not sufficiently complicated for me to recommend that, but with self-employment, the forms and legal requirements can get very complicated. At an absolute minimum, you should probably set up some kind of withholding for what's left of 2021, and continue withholding into 2022 and beyond. Assuming that you ultimately get a W-2, this is a matter of filing form W-4 and specifying the amount you want withheld. If you get some kind of 1099, then it's a complicated mess.

Answer (score 2):

You can (and probably should) pay any missed quarterly taxes as soon as you can.

You will probably have to pay a penalty but the interest charges will be minimized.